# RETENTION TO A TABLE IN SAS VIYA 3.4

Tags: sas

I am facing a request lately and any ideas would be appreciated.

I have a lot of tables in SAS Viya 3.4 App I want to set a retention period to all of them. ( for example 12 months )

Every table contains a column named "PDATE".
The PDATE column contains dates in a character format.

An example of this : "20201231"
(The above example refers to 31 December of 2020)

I have tables:

- in memory ( CAS tables )
- in an HDFS CASLIB ( CAS tables )
- in a directory on server ( .sas7bdat )

ALL OF THEM contain `PDATE` column in the same format.

I want to set a retention period to all of them.

I thought to

1. convert the biggest PDATE value ( which is the latest in time ) of each table to a date format.
2. to find the "latest value" - 365
3. convert the result from step 2 into a character format (like "20191231)
4. write a few lines of code after that creating a new table like:

```
data mycaslib.tablenew;
  set mycaslib.tableold;
  where PDATE < "foundvalue";
run;
```

5. then to drop the original table form the memory and promote the new one.

I know this is a solution but I also know that is not efficient cause I have to deal with over 100 millions of rows.

Is the partitioning of the tables a solution?
How could that be implemented?

Any other ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: We have a similar request in the backlog for Data Controller (https://datacontroller.io) -> we could easily deliver this as a supported feature, feel free to contact me on the site above.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an index on `pdate` may help better than partitioning. Partitioning is more for improving the performance of by-group processing. I would recommend converting `pdate` to a SAS date for *all* tables and adding an index on it instead.

Indexes in CAS work on `where` statements only, which is exactly what you need. If you wanted to index your data, use the `table.Index` CAS action Note that the `index` option is not yet supported and would need to be done with either a CAS action or `proc casutil`.

```
cas;
libname casuser cas caslib='casuser';

data casuser.cars;
    set sashelp.cars;
run;

proc cas;
    table.index result=r /
        table={caslib  = 'casuser'
               name    = 'cars'
        }
        casout={caslib    = 'casuser'
                name      = 'cars_indexed'
                indexvars = {'make'}
                replace   = true
        }
    ;
    
    table.tableDetails /
        caslib = 'casuser'
        name   = 'cars_indexed'
    ;
quit;
```

You could set up all of these tables such that they are loaded with an index on the SAS-converted value of `pdate`.

When you get to Viya 3.5 or higher, you'll be able to modify tables directly with the `table.deleteRows` action. This will allow you to modify everything in-place.

```
proc cas;
    table.deleteRows result=r / 
        table={caslib = 'casuser'
               name   = 'cars'
               where='make = "BMW"'
        }
    ;
    
    simple.numRows result=n
        table={caslib = 'casuser'
               name   = 'cars'
               where='make = "BMW"'
        }
    ;
    
    put n;
quit;
```